# iOS App Store app crashes during login (not in development)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, userdefaults

So this may be because UserDefaults are getting reset after a period of time, maybe because I update the OS frequently, but a released version of my iOS app after a period of time will crash on my login screen, probably where I check for saved credentials (in UserDefaults). Reinstalling the app fixes the issue. Console returns a lot of :

Unsupported use of UIKit view-customization API off the main thread. -setAlignsToKeyboard: sent to <_UIAlertControllerView: 0x125b2d070; frame = (0 0; 414 896); layer = <CALayer: 0x283f652e0>>

And my system logs show an error on this thread:

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread: 4

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

> Thread 4 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-delegate Thread
> 4 Crashed: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001bfb4e414 0x1bfb26000 +
> 164884 1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001dd6a8b50 0x1dd6a6000 +
> 11088 2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x000000019b027b74 0x19afb1000 + 486260 3
> libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001a6d1acf8 0x1a6d07000 + 81144 4
> libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001a6d0be4c 0x1a6d07000 + 20044 5
> libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001a6c14f64 0x1a6c0e000 + 28516 6
> libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001a6d1a0e0 0x1a6d07000 + 78048 7
> libc++abi.dylib 0x00000001a6d1a06c 0x1a6d07000 + 77932 8
> libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001917eddc4 0x1917ea000 + 15812 9
> libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001917f510c 0x1917ea000 + 45324 10
> libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001917f5c90 0x1917ea000 + 48272 11
> libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001917ffd78 0x1917ea000 + 89464 12
> libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001dd6a9814 0x1dd6a6000 + 14356 13
> libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001dd6b076c 0x1dd6a6000 + 42860

Here is some code that I use to check saved credentials. In the backend API I cannot see any login attempts. If it helps, I can see this viewcontroller for a split second right before it crashes. Not sure if that rules out viewdidload.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addLoadingSpinner()
    bLogIn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.setToVoiceLight()
    self.tfCustomerID.delegate = self
    self.tfUsername.delegate = self
    self.tfPassword.delegate = self
    tfUsername.keyboardType = .default
    tfPassword.textContentType = .password
    setupUI()
    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.session) != nil
        && UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.savedCred) == "True" {
        login_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.session)!
        check_session()
    }
    else if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.savedCred) == "True" &&
            UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.usesBiometrics) == "True" {
        promptTouchOrFaceID()
    }
    removeLoadingSpinner()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo:
                                            UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)
    cbSave.isChecked = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.savedCred) == "True"
    addObservers()
}

func check_session() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(login_session, forKey: "session")
    UserInfo.access_token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "session")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: checksession_url)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = .GET
    request.addValues(...)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {
            //VERIFIED THAT NEVER GETTING TO API
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                ...
            }
        } else {
            self.promptTouchOrFaceID()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.session)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Here is my code for biometrics prompt:

```
func promptTouchOrFaceID() {
    //create context for touch auth
    let authenticationContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    authenticationContext.localizedFallbackTitle = ""
    let biometricType = authenticationContext.biometricType
    //check if the device has a fingerprint sensor, exit if not
    guard authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
                                                  error: &error) else {
        let title = "Error"
        var message = ""
        switch biometricType {
        case .faceID:
            message = "This device does not have a FaceID sensor or the sensor is not enabled."
        case .touchID:
            message = "This device does not have a TouchID sensor or the sensor is not enabled."
        case .none:
            message = "This device does not have any sensors to use TouchID or FaceID"
        }

        AlertService.showAlert(on: self, title: title, message: message)
        UserDefaults.standard.set("False", forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.usesBiometrics)
        removeLoadingSpinner()
        return
    }
    authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
                                         localizedReason: "Please use your fingerprint to authenticate.",
                                         reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in
                                            if (success) {
                                                //fingerprint recognized, set this possible and go to view controller
                                                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                                                    self.fillInUserDetails()
                                                    self.login_now(
                                                        username:self.tfUsername.text!,
                                                        password: self.userDefaults.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.password)!,
                                                        customer: self.tfCustomerID.text!)
                                                })
                                            }
                                         })

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild shot, but do you have `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` key in your plist file. I remember having a problem like this a few months back.

Comment: I'll take wild shots.  I do have it listed.  Thanks